# How can I run a PHP file and archive the output?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a PHP file whose output I want to add to a zip archive (using PHP's `ZipArchive` class). However, when I try to add it, it just gives me the PHP source code, unprocessed. **How do I ensure the PHP is run and processed before adding it to the zip?**

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<?PHP
$z = $_GET['z']; // something like 'css-js-Type', etc.
$cols = $_GET['cols']; // a number
if (!$z)
{
    header("Location: /husk/get/");
    exit();
}
if ($cols)
    $cols = intval($cols);
else
    $cols = 12;

$zname = 'Husk_' . $z . "_$cols".'col' . '_' . getHuskVersion() . '.zip';
$here = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/prog/husk';
$filename = "$here/get/$zname";
if (!file_exists ($filename))
{
    $z = explode ('-', $z);

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE)
        exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");

    $_GET['cols'] = $cols;
    if (in_array('css', $z))
        $zip->addFile("$here\\_css\\HuskGen.php", "Husk_$cols.css");
    if (in_array('js', $z))
        $zip->addFile("$here\\_js\\Husk.jQuery.js", 'Husk.jQuery.js');
    if (in_array('Flex', $z))
        $zip->addFile("$here\\_css\\Flex.css", 'Flex.css');
    if (in_array('Type', $z))
        $zip->addFile("$here\\_css\\Type.css", 'Type.css');
    if (in_array('Print', $z))
        $zip->addFile("$here\\_css\\Print.css", 'Print.css');

    echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
    echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
    $zip->close();
}

header("Location: /husk/get/$zname");
?>
```

Comment: Initiate a real request to your web server, i.e. don't use `file_get_contents` or related functions to access the file on the hard drive. Pass a URL.

Comment: You want to add php open source or what is generated? Tried `ob_start()`+`ob_get_contents`+`ZipArchive::addFromString`?

Comment: You're here for three years now and should know the rules. Give us some code, please...

Comment: Crap yeah, sorry! Code added!

Comment: So, what happens when you run this file?  How are you trying to run this file?  What is this file named?

Comment: I guess you don't want the source of `HuskGen.php` in that ZIP but its output?

Comment: @RocketHazmat When I run the code above, it gives me the `js` and `css` files just as I want them, but `HuskGen.php` is just added as the PHP source code to the zip archive

Comment: `ZipArchive::addFile` returns `boolean`, this helps to verify that the code has been executed, it returns `false` you delete the "zip" file and issue an error message to the user.

Comment: @LinusKleen no, I want its processed result in the zup output

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento the file is successfully added, but not processed by PHP beforehand.

Comment: You say "How do I ensure the PHP is run and processed before adding it to the zip", not only specified that php file.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: What I understand is this: You want the "HuskGen.php" file is processed together before adding to "zip", but that should be added to "zip" is just the result of "HuskGen.php" (the output)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento yes

Comment: My first comment here is almost the answer, but you do not answer it, so I had no way of knowing what you want.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I think your first comment is almost the perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file is a file. The "extension" does not matter when reading it.

If you need a PHP script to be *interpreted*, you'll have to do this yourself (this does *not* work for anything *but* PHP scripts):

```
 ob_start();
 require "myscript.php";
 $contents = ob_get_clean();
```

Then, `$contents` can be added to the ZIP file.

This approach, however, is naive, since it relies on the required PHP script to execute cleanly and deliver all the required output to STDOUT. Which PHP scripts tend *not* to do.

Depending on your `php.ini` (or other settings), warnings, errors or other things produced while executing the script that are not meant for public release **will** be included in your ZIP archive as well.

Comment: Exactly what I said in my first comment. +1

Comment: Hello, revenge downvoter. I have [more answers to downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/users/255756/linus-kleen?tab=answers) for you.

Comment: I gave you a upvote and not a downvote. I think the message is for someone else. Unfortunately there are users so have patience, you helped a lot here in the "SO". Congratulations for your contribution!